# How to create url preview in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, preview

Can someone help me with creation of a url previews in JavaScript?

What I mean is this: Say I have a link on my site, I want the user to be able to mouse over the link, and have an image pop up that shows what the target of the link looks like.

Don't worry about the css, I got that working, I just need the actual script to show the image.

Currently I am doing it by showing up an iframe that actually renders the page, but this is not scalable and looks ugly.

Having the page display premade images is not an option, since the links will be linking to dynamically generated user content.

Comment: Could a mod give this a 'PHP' or '.net' tag? There really isn't a way for this to be done in JS alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to have pre-stored images. Javascript cannot take screenshots and resize the images (for now). Try this: http://snapcasa.com/ . It takes images dynamically for you. All you have to do is to hot link the images :)

The best features when using http://snapcasa.com/:

1. Images are guaranteed to be most up-to-date
2. You don't have to store them on your server!
3. Free plan has lots of credits for you to burn!

Comment: The link http://snapcasa.com is dead

Answer (score 3):

Daniel is right there is no way the client could do this, but an option would be a free thumnail service; http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/ combined with a nice tooltip script: http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried out snapcasa (which was also mentioned by the first response), and it works! I made my own tooltips code, but the plugin you linked me looks nice, I'll keep it in mind for future projects.

Comment: We have the error 404 on your 2 links

Comment: @LucasBodin the answer is 12 years old: try https://web.archive.org/

Answer (score 3):

If you want more direct control over your screenshots and want to configure things on the server, you can set up [khtml2png](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/) or [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/)* to generate images on the command line. (And [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=188884&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a) is some direction toward using Gecko if you prefer that.)

* webkit2png provides instructions for OS X, but there's really no reason it shouldn't work on *nix, being that WebKit itself is cross-platform. Figuring that out can be left as an exercise to the reader, but it may be worthwhile as KHTML has historically lagged behind WebKit for new (HTML5, CSS3, etc) features.

I haven't tested any of these solutions, but it might be enough to get started if you want more control over the screenshot generation.

Answer (score 3):

## 2022 Update

At last, 10 years later someone created a library to achieve this task. You can download and get more information on their [github](https://github.com/ospfranco/link-preview-js).

In a nutshell what it does :

> Extract web links information: title, description, images, videos,
> etc. [via OpenGraph], runs on mobiles and node.

This plugin was written utilizing [OpenGraph](https://ogp.me/).

You can easily use this very simple [OpenGraph API](https://www.opengraph.io/).

For raw material and knowledge read about OpenGraph and maybe create your own library and plugin if what you find on github isn't satisfying enough.

As an example, the following is the Open Graph protocol markup for The Rock on IMDB:

```
<html prefix="og: https://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Rock (1996)</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />
...
</head>
...
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Website previews cannot be generated on the client-side. The preview image needs to be rendered on the server, which can then be called into your HTML document with a simple `<img>` tag.

Basically you could have an image tag such as the following:

```
<img src="/my_preview_renderer.php?site=www.google.com" />
```

... where `my_preview_renderer.php` will generate the preview in realtime and return the image data with the appropriate mime-type. You can use any server side scripting language.

This is not an exhaustive answer, but I hope that it can point you to the right direction.

Comment: So how would I go about doing it server side?

Comment: @Razor: I will leave it for that for the other answers, as I have no actual experience in preview generation. However I understand that it is not trivial to generate previews, especially when the websites use JavaScript, flash, and other plugins.

Comment: @RazorStorm i need your help to solve my problem, i want to Build a small application. There needs to be a text box and when I paste a link in the text box, I need to see the preview.[ its like when we paste any link while chatting in facebook, we will get the small preview for that given link ]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an iframe, or pay for a service that takes screenshots (Doctype.com offer this, I think). The paid service will still take a long time to generate screenshots. Basically, don't bother trying, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

well, i think since all answers here are a bit old, now you can do this using the built in web-kit tools in most current browsers, using webrtc,or ffmpeg tools available in js such an approach can be done in minutes