# Live Preview of an http:// site Script / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, live, preview

I would like to put a live preview of another site on my site as my portfolio.
But i don't know if any script/jQuery exists. I could not find anything.
My own page is in HTML5 and the iFrame script for a live preview is not working very well, cause I cannot get the iFrame on the right format:(X+Y)
So my question is:

Does any jQuery script allow me to do this and where can i find it?
And is it possible to show an image instead of a 404 page, if the site is offline?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: No, jQuery has nothing to do with this, iFrame is the best way to go.

Comment: Interesting idea, but you're giving up control as to what is displayed on your site. For your portfolio, I'd suggest static screenshots that link to the other site.

Comment: Another option depending on the type of site and your clients, you could host a dummy version of the site on a sub-domain. I use demo.myportfolio.com/<clientwebsite>/, but you could also have <clientwebsite>.myportfolio.com. At least you know it's always up and in the same condition when you passed it over to them.

Comment: @Hogan Do you have a good script for HTML5? When i put on the normal script my site is loading slow. And an other thing: My site is mobile-friendly, so it must also work on mobile devices... or not be shown on mobile devices.

Comment: Chek this discussion
[hot to create url preview in javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715752/how-to-create-url-preview-in-javascript